# sudo 1.8.16 update wants to wipe out my sudo privilege?

Tags: upgrade, sudo, etc

Ran dist-upgrade today and noticed that sudo update wants to rewrite my /etc/sudoers. Upon reading the diff it seems that my sudo privilege would be removed by that update.

Found related question here (unfortunately closed, so I couldn't react):
https://serverfault.com/questions/800112/ec2-ubuntu-server-sudo-lock-out-bug-sudoers-update

Pasted log from my console here (jiri is my username): http://pastebin.com/wZkMFFux

Kept my current version of config file, but if I did overwrite it, I understand that I would lose sudo privileges on my production server without any chance to get it back.

What does it mean? Is this normal behaviour of sudo update? It seems quite dangerous to me...

Comment: May I ask what was the exact command you typed to run `dist-upgrade`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that

- `/snap/bin` is added to the `secure_path` variable, which should be done, at least if you have any snaps installed.
- `jiri   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` would be removed, which granted the user `jiri` full root-`sudo` privileges.

So the second change would remove user `jiri`'s explicitly configured `sudo` privilege.

However, on Ubuntu you should normally not add user accounts to `/etc/sudoers` manually but add them to the user group `sudo` instead. That one is configured by the line `%sudo    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` which obviously stays intact.

So if your user `jiri` is in the `sudo` group (verify by running `groups jiri`), you can remove that line in question without worries. If not, you should add user `jiri` to the `sudo` group (by running `sudo adduser jiri sudo`) and remove the line in question afterwards.

Comment: Is that system configured to allow jiri to act as root without sudo'ing?...

Comment: @T.J.L. No, that is impossible. The `/etc/sudoers` config file only controls the behaviour of `sudo`.

Comment: That's what I thought. I can't figure out why this was done in the first place.

Comment: @T.J.L. It was configured to grant user `jiri` explicit sudo privileges instead of doing it via the `sudo` user group. Maybe that's how folks are supposed to do it on Debian or Arch or so, they don't use `sudo` the way we do on Ubuntu IIRC.

Comment: I'm sure that I didn't add user `jiri` to `/etc/sudoers`, I have no idea how it happened to be there (now I can see it's not there on my main PC). User `jiri` is also correctly in `sudo` group as you said, so I'm going to apply the patch manually. Thanks for your explanation.